# MongoDB - Query document by same field from multiple objects in array

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "AouRpb5g2WR9sZe5z",
  "participants" : [ 
    {
        "user" : "CYvApwRFADveqBqEY",
        "unread" : false
    }, 
    {
        "user" : "sgoinZkaHbqth8nPr",
        "unread" : false
    }
   ],
 "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-07-23T04:06:53.748Z")
}
```

I need to be able to find the document that has both users `'CYvApwRFADveqBqEY'` and `'sgoinZkaHbqth8nPr'`. I was able to find all documents with one of the users with `elemMatch`, but couldn't figure it out for both, or if that's even the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `find` query with an [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/), you can do :

```
db.device.find({
  "participants.user": {
    $all: ["CYvApwRFADveqBqEY", "sgoinZkaHbqth8nPr"]
  }
});
```

From the doc of `$all` :

> The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an >array that contains all the specified elements.

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly.